# Opened an account someplace where I don't live

Tags: united-states, bank-account, checking-account

So I was visiting Miami, when I opened a bank account there. I live in CA and I got a job here. I was asked regarding my bank details and was wondering if i should give the routing number of Miami or CA? And what bank address if i give CA?

Comment: @keshlam routing numbers can vary between branches of the same bank.  You should call the bank.

Answer (score 1):

You should give the routing number appearing on your checks. If in doubt - call the bank and ask them.

Many banks have multiple routing numbers, but often they cannot be used interchangeably. In some cases there are explicitly separate organizations within the bank, and while for you the branches all look the same - internally they are not necessarily working as a whole.

Comment: If you don't have a checkbook, the bank may also allow you to get the routing number in its online system - this is how I usually get mine.